# Qt- How to add a scroll bar for the xAxis of a big QBarChart

Tags: c++, qt, bar-chart

I am making a histogram with the count of each pixel in a grayscale image. That means I have 255 bars in my bar chart. It looks like the below and I can't make it expand.

[image]

And this is the code that I wrote:

```
Histogram::Histogram()
{
    ui = std::make_unique<Ui_GraphWindow>();
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true); // delete the object after the window is closed


    ui->chartView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    ui->chartView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);        
}

void Histogram::display(QImage * image)
{
    show();

    std::map<size_t, size_t> colorCount;    
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        colorCount[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < image->width(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image->height(); j++) {
            auto val = qGray(image->pixel(i, j));
            colorCount[val]++;
        }
    }
    QStringList categories;


    std::vector<QBarSet*> sets(colorCount.size());
    QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();

    for (int i = 0; i < colorCount.size(); i++) {
        sets[i] = new QBarSet(std::to_string(i).c_str());

        *sets[i] << colorCount[i];
        sets[i]->setColor(QColor(i, i, i));
        sets[i]->setBorderColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
        series->append(sets[i]);
    }

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setTitle("Simple barchart example");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations);

    QBarCategoryAxis *axis = new QBarCategoryAxis();
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    axis->append(categories);
    chart->setAxisX(axis, series);

    chart->legend()->setVisible(false);
    ui->chartView->setChart(chart);
    ui->chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
}
```

Even if I added scrollbars it won't work. I want to be able to scroll horizontally. I tried to use `zoomIn()` but it did not work, and `scale()` does make it bigger but with no scrollbars appear and I can only see a part of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
chart->legend()->setVisible(false);
ui->chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
// the magic is done with setRubberBand()
chartView->setRubberBand(QChartView::HorizontalRubberBand);
ui->chartView->setChart(chart); //try this if the other one does not work with your version of qt:  chartView->setParent(ui->histoPlot);
```

If the left mouse button is pressed and the rubber band is enabled,
... the rubber band is displayed on the screen.
This enables the user to really select the zoom area by using the mouse.
Check out what I mean here, [the action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS0zI.png) and [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGZFd.png)
How to come back to our main selected area that was not expanded?
Just by clicking multiple times with rigth button of the mouse.

Moreover, it will be more readable if you add more details about X axis:

```
axisX = new QValueAxis();
chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom); // Add a horizontal X axis at the bottom of the chart
    barseries->attachAxis(axisX);
    axisX->applyNiceNumbers();
          
// Setting Range to be precise of making the whole data visible
    axisX->setRange(0,256); // because you have a histogram
```